# What's the lowest that you'll find lava in the nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is the lowest level where lava in the lava oceans will go down to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just went to the Nether and did some research with WorldEdit's `//count`.

Here's how lava is distributed in a 200x200 area:

```
LB: 0  0  0  0  31 65 30 22 18 19  30  20  20  18  17  18  15  14  9   7   1   168  382  1879  5594  6864  8200  10084  12393  14205  16219  18187  71  38  42  44  55  57  48  85  46  50  52  55  38
%:  0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0% 0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%   0%   1%   5%    14%   17%   20%   25%    31%    36%    41%    45%   0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
Y: 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21   22   23    24    25    26    27     28     29     30     31     32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45
```

(`LB` - lava blocks in a 200x200 layer at the `Y` coordinate; `%` - percentage)

We can see that there's lava starting almost at the very bottom. But big amounts of lava start only from Y: 23, so that may be the answer to your question.

Comment: Your data would be somewhat more useful if it A) Included a larger area, and B) Gave an idea of how much air there is, for comparison.

Comment: @WillihamTotland As there are no biomes in the Nether, the small sample size may not be too big an issue. But you're right that to have more confidence in the answer, it might be nice to see samples from a few locations or a few world keys.

Comment: @WillihamTotland I wasn't sure about what would happen if I applied `//count` to unloaded chunks, so that's why the area is so small. And I didn't do more tests, because I was collecting the data manually, layer by layer, and that's quite time consuming.